# I am trying to implement push notification in ionic v1using onesignal-cordova-plugin,fcm.But it's not working.My app.js is given below

Tags: ionic-framework

var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
        console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        };

```
    window.plugins.OneSignal.init("MY APP ID",
    {googleProjectNumber:"Project Number"},
    notificationOpenedCallback);

  // Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your app.
    window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);
```